What sound would a dripping faucet produce if the dripping pattern had two distinct frequencies from a mathematical perspective?
I'm preparing some introductory lessons for high school students, where I aim to explain the duality between the time and frequency domains. To make the concept more relatable, I thought of using a simple real-world example: the dripping of a faucet.
Here's the question:
Suppose I record the time instances when water droplets from a leaking faucet hit the sink. I assume that the dripping pattern is not perfectly regular but shows some variations in the timing between consecutive droplets. Could this irregular dripping produce a signal with two distinct frequencies? From a mathematical perspective, what kind of sound would this produce, and how would it differ from a regular, single-frequency drip?
For comparison, if the dripping were purely periodic, say with a droplet falling exactly every second, the sound I would hear would be like drip...drip...drip... at perfectly regular intervals. This corresponds to a signal with only one frequency. How would an irregular dripping pattern differ in this case? To be more specific, if there were two frequencies, what kind of sound would I hear?
Understanding this would be really helpful for explaining to students how even simple time-domain patterns can have complex frequency-domain representations.
Thank you in advance!

I don't understand exactly what's asked, but: (i) A real non-periodic faucet is chaotic, not well-modeled by a superposition of two constant-frequency drips. (ii) If we superpose two periodic drips, what we hear qualitatively depends on whether the ratio of periods (or frequencies) is rational or not. If so, we can model by making each period a whole multiple of a common denominator. (iii) You and your students might enjoy Steve Reich's Music for Pieces of Wood.
